# Ruby DSL - invoking user-provided methods within block context

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

A user of my Ruby DSL wishes to be able to add additional methods and invoke them within the context of an arbitrary block, for example:

```
def do_something
  override 'flags', 'ABC'        
end

project('XXX') do
  configuration('debug') do
    do_something
  end
end
```

In this sample, 'override' is a method of the configuration object that's invoked with instance_eval.

Is there a way of forcing any method calls to be executed within the context of the configuration block, so that 'override' for example can be resolved and executed?

[edit]

So I construct the root DSL object and evaluate as follows:

```
root_dsl = DSL.new
root_dsl.instance_eval(File.read(filename))
```

This DSL class has a method on it matching 'project' from the above sample:

```
def project(&block) do
    project_dsl = ProjectDSL.new
    project_dsl.instance_eval(&block)
end
```

And the project_dsl class has a method on it matching 'configuration' from the above example:

```
def configuration(name, &block) do
   configuration_dsl = ProjectConfigDSL.new(name)
   configuration_dsl.instance_eval(&block)
end
```

And so on. The user wants his defined method in the DSL file itself to execute within the context of the ProjectConfigDSL object.

Comment: Would you mind to share the DSL implementation itself?

Comment: @mudasobwa I've added further implementation details as requested

Answer (score 0):

The way I'm doing this in my own code is to make the helper function return a proc that gets passed to instance_eval. for example:

```
def do_something
  Proc.new do
    override 'flags', 'ABC'
  end        
end

project('XXX') do
  configuration 'debug', &do_something
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was unaware that instance_eval sandboxes scope to that instance, so what I've had to do is delegate from the root DSL object with executing the block directly and forwarding calls in missing_method to a child DSL object, and repeat this pattern the whole way down.

By doing this it fixes the scoping issue, but it does cause a new issue of collliding method names being forwarded to the wrong objects. Fortunately my DSL hasn't run into that issue yet, so this will be good enough for now.